# Gradle Sync failed with no specific error after update to Android Studio 3.2 - Android Gradle plugin 3.2.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I recently updated both the IDE and, if I, as suggested, update the Gradle Plugin to version 3.2.0, I can't Sync my project. The event log on Android Studio just reports `Gradle sync failed`.
I tried:

- cleanBuildCache
- Restart
- Invalidate IDE cache
- Do everything again, just in case

This is the IDEA log:

```
2018-09-28 10:19:36,543 [e-1136-b06]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Consuming IndexingSuspender activation event: SYNC_TASK_CREATED 
2018-09-28 10:19:36,545 [e-1136-b06]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Started sync with Gradle for project '***'. 
2018-09-28 10:19:36,548 [e-1136-b06]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Consuming IndexingSuspender activation event: SYNC_STARTED 
2018-09-28 10:19:36,548 [e-1136-b06]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Starting batch update for project: Project '/Users/***/Documents/***/android/lib' com.***.***.lib 
2018-09-28 10:19:36,557 [thread 314]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home 
2018-09-28 10:19:36,558 [thread 314]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home 
2018-09-28 10:19:36,565 [thread 314]   INFO - xecution.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: -Didea.version=3.2 -Djava.awt.headless=true -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only=true -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only.advanced=true -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only.versioned=3 -Pandroid.injected.studio.version=3.2.0.26 -Pandroid.builder.sdkDownload=false --init-script /private/var/folders/n8/8s0k679x36xdch74kff4y_r8n13428/T/ijinit.gradle 
2018-09-28 10:19:37,538 [thread 314]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Started setup of project 'com.***.***.lib'. 
2018-09-28 10:19:37,540 [e-1136-b06]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Consuming IndexingSuspender activation event: SETUP_STARTED 
2018-09-28 10:19:38,157 [e-1136-b06]   INFO - ule.android.SdkModuleSetupStep - Set Android SDK 'Android API 28 Platform' (/Users/***/Library/Android/sdk) to module 'datalink' 
2018-09-28 10:19:38,187 [e-1136-b06]   INFO - ule.android.SdkModuleSetupStep - Set Android SDK 'Android API 28 Platform' (/Users/***/Library/Android/sdk) to module 'connection' 
2018-09-28 10:19:38,190 [e-1136-b06]   INFO - ule.android.SdkModuleSetupStep - Set Android SDK 'Android API 28 Platform' (/Users/***/Library/Android/sdk) to module 'transport' 
2018-09-28 10:19:38,209 [e-1136-b06]   INFO - ule.android.SdkModuleSetupStep - Set Android SDK 'Android API 28 Platform' (/Users/***/Library/Android/sdk) to module 'vehicle' 
2018-09-28 10:19:38,381 [thread 314]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Gradle sync failed (1 s 836 ms) 
2018-09-28 10:19:38,389 [e-1136-b06]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Consuming IndexingSuspender deactivation event: SYNC_FINISHED 
2018-09-28 10:19:38,389 [e-1136-b06]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Finishing batch update for project: Project '/Users/***/Documents/***/android/lib' com.***.***.lib 
2018-09-28 10:19:38,427 [e-1136-b06]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed 
2018-09-28 10:19:38,565 [thread 171]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 25ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2018-09-28 10:19:38,592 [thread 171]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 27ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2018-09-28 10:19:38,775 [thread 171]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Clearing symbols finished in 0.005 s. 
2018-09-28 10:19:38,776 [thread 171]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols in FAST mode, 0 source files from total 0 project files 
2018-09-28 10:19:38,777 [thread 171]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading symbols finished in 0.002 s. 
2018-09-28 10:19:38,777 [thread 171]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading Header Maps finished in 0.000 s. 
2018-09-28 10:19:38,777 [thread 171]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading Module Maps finished in 0.000 s. 
2018-09-28 10:19:38,778 [thread 171]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving Module Maps finished in 0.001 s. 
2018-09-28 10:19:38,778 [thread 171]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loaded 0 tables for 0 files (0 project files) 
2018-09-28 10:19:38,778 [thread 171]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols for 0 source files 
2018-09-28 10:19:38,778 [thread 171]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols for 0 unused headers 
2018-09-28 10:19:38,778 [thread 171]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols finished in 0.000 s. 
2018-09-28 10:19:38,778 [thread 171]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving modified symbols for 0 files (0 tables of total 0) 
2018-09-28 10:19:38,779 [thread 171]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving symbols finished in 0.000 s.
```

Running `./gradlew build` builds successfully, but Studio still complains that `Gradle project sync failed` and I can't run stuff.

Android Studio 3.2 /
Android Gradle Plugin 3.2.0 /
Gradle wrapper 4.10.2 /
MacOS High Sierra 10.13.4

Any kind of help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: have you tried building the project with the command line using `./gradlew build`?

Comment: @da_berni Thanks for your help. That command runs successfully, but the IDE still complains. I'll add that to the question

Comment: So it's really just the IDE. Another try would be to delete the `.idea` folder in your projects directory, this will require a complete new import of the project.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help. But I found out that things work if I don't follow the recommendation to update the Gradle plugin to version 3.2.0
I'm updating the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with the brand new gradle, gradle android plugin and Android Studio 3.2

I have created a separate test project and started moving my current project modules one by one in order to identify the sync problem.

In my case the problem was caused by mismatched minSdkVersion in the library manifest file.

In my project I have a bunch of android libraries that have minSdkVersion set inside their manifest files. In previous gradle plugin / Android Studio versions the sync process ignored these manifest values in favor of the ones defined in build.gradle files. In the new version of gradle plugin it seems to be a problem.

What I have done: removed all minSdkVersion/targetSdkVersion xml entries from library/app manifests. Now my project syncs properly.

Hope to help.

Comment: Yasss that worked. I had a similar situation with libraris having minSdkVersion in their manifest and not in their build.gradle. Just moved it to the gradle file and everything works. Thanks!